# Inventory numbers wrong , Heavy Load under Sale

Tags: magento-1.9

We experienced a heavy load sale where the site was as maximum load and we did around 2500 orders in a day. What seemed to of happened is that we sold 3 items when we only had 1.

We run some modules that cancel pending orders and add stock back into database.

The actual database was under heavy load , is it possible that inventory malfunctioned for around 7% of sales ?